# Traversing in Vb.NET

Tags: vb.net

I need to traverse in VB.Net
I have 4 command buttons namely Move First, Previous, Next and Last.
I m using MS Access as my6 back end.
If i press move first i should get first element
If i press move previous i should get prev element
If i press move last i should get last element
If i press move next i should get next element

Comment: Traverse records retrieved from database? You need to make your question clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but have a look at the following:
[Paging Through a Query Result (ADO.NET)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tx1c9c2f.aspx)